# Using Outlooks COM class component fails only with admin privileges

Tags: windows, powershell, outlook, com, uac

I have a PowerShell script which queries the current Outlook session.

Running it just in an unelevated PowerShell window works like expected, but when I'm in an elevated prompt it fails like demonstrated below:

"normal" session:

```
PS> New-Object -Com Outlook.Application


Application        : System.__ComObject
Class              : 0
Session            : System.__ComObject
Parent             :
Assistant          :
Name               : Outlook
Version            : 15.0.0.4903
COMAddIns          : System.__ComObject
Explorers          : System.__ComObject
Inspectors         : System.__ComObject
LanguageSettings   : System.__ComObject
ProductCode        : {90150000-000F-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
AnswerWizard       :
FeatureInstall     : 1
Reminders          : System.__ComObject
DefaultProfileName : Outlook
IsTrusted          : False
Assistance         : System.__ComObject
TimeZones          : System.__ComObject
PickerDialog       : System.__ComObject
```

Elevated one:

```
PS> New-Object -Com Outlook.Application
New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed
due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005
(CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
At line:1 char:1
+ New-Object -Com Outlook.Application
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Elevation uses the same user account, which is in the Administrator group. Why does this happen? And how to fix it? As I know un-elevated applications are not allowed to communicate directly with elevated ones, but the other way around should work, shouldn't it? I also tried to start Outlook as Administrator but - like expected - it doesn't make any difference.

EDIT:

```
C:/WINDOWS/system32> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.693
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.693
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

It's PoSh 5 on Win 10 with Office 2013 Home & Business

Comment: If you start outlook up as an elevated session do you still get the same outlook profiles load as you do in a non elevated session?

Comment: Yes, stays the same.

Comment: I can reproduce your issue if I have Outlook open or if I first create the instance in the normal session open. My elevated New-Object works just fine if Outlook is closed an no one has a connection through COM. My best educated guess is that you can't connect to Outlook with multiple processes having different elevation levels. As to the why that would be, I honestly have no real idea.

Comment: Using procmon, it might be that this is just a sharing violation to my pst files. If that's your case too, this ends up having nothing to do with elevation to begin with.

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce it this way. The thing is, if the elevated PowerShell holds the object I'm unable to start Outlook unelevated. (says another version of Outlook is open) It seems that there is no solution. Confusing that I can open as much PoSh processes as I want in the same elevation level w/o having trouble...

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers This sounds like a good possible answer. (would you post it?) I don't want to ping specific users to specific questions, but will leave this open and do some research on this. Thanks.

Comment: @Clijsters - I'm freewheeling here but my take on this is that there's no sharing violation between processes having the same elevation level because they use shared memory. Another elevation level process can't use that same shared memory and has to open and read the pst files. As they are already exlusively opened, a sharing violation occurs. I have added a `windows` tag to your question and hope to attract some experts on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@Lieven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52598/lieven-keersmaekers) on helping me researching this issue. I wanted to leave this open if someone comes around and finds a solution on this. As stated out by [@Lieven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52598/lieven-keersmaekers) and some ongoing research on myself, **there is no "solution" for this**:

Outlook and PowerShell can concurrently use the same Outlook session using shared memory. As processes with different elevation levels can't share memory (reference needed), the 2nd process (elevated PowerShell in my case) has to open the PST (a new outlook session) by itself, which fails because it's exclusively opened by the first one (unelevated Outlook in my case).

My workaround is to create a low-level process holding the Outlook session and [providing a pipeline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream(v=vs.110).aspx) for higher level processes (and same-level as well) to connect with. Vice versa won't work as unelevated processes are not allowed to connect to elevated pipelines.

This works for me as the tasks doing with the Outlook session from PowerShell are very basic. However it is still a workaround.